# Why does SpeechRecognition library not work with temporary audio file?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, cherrypy

My goal is to receive an audio file from client and transcribe it to text without permanently saving to disk. I'm using SpeechRecognition library and it works perfectly if uploaded file is saved, but when i try to use temporary file it leads to error.

From CherryPy docs:

> When a client uploads a file to a CherryPy application, it’s placed on disk immediately. CherryPy will pass it to your exposed method as an argument; that arg will have a “file” attribute, which is a handle to the temporary uploaded file

Since the `sr.AudioFile` constructor also accepts a 'file-like object', i'm using `io.BytesIO` to pass the content of temporary file to constructor.

Here's the code of my server:

```py
import io
import cherrypy
import speech_recognition as sr

class HttpServer(object):    
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self, ufile):
        ufile_content = ufile.file.read() # reading temp file
        buffer = io.BytesIO(ufile_content)
        buffer.seek(0)
        with sr.AudioFile(buffer) as source:
            audio = self.recognizer.record(source)
        result = self.recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language='ru-RU')
```

I'm using this code to send request to the server:

```py
import requests
url = 'http://localhost:8080/'
files = {'ufile': ('audio.flac', open('audio.flac', 'rb'), 'audio/flac')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 203, in __enter__
    self.audio_reader = wave.open(self.filename_or_fileobject, "rb")
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wave.py", line 510, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wave.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wave.py", line 131, in initfp
    raise Error('file does not start with RIFF id')
wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 208, in __enter__
    self.audio_reader = aifc.open(self.filename_or_fileobject, "rb")
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\aifc.py", line 917, in open
    return Aifc_read(f)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\aifc.py", line 358, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\aifc.py", line 316, in initfp
    raise Error('file does not start with FORM id')
aifc.Error: file does not start with FORM id

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 234, in __enter__
    self.audio_reader = aifc.open(aiff_file, "rb")
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\aifc.py", line 917, in open
    return Aifc_read(f)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\aifc.py", line 358, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\aifc.py", line 314, in initfp
    chunk = Chunk(file)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\chunk.py", line 63, in __init__
    raise EOFError
EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 628, in respond
    self._do_respond(path_info)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 687, in _do_respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\encoding.py", line 219, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpdispatch.py", line 54, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "new1.py", line 19, in index
    with audio_file as source:
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 236, in __enter__
    raise ValueError("Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format")
ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format
```

Does anyone have any solutions to the problem?

Comment: Plz, don't use `bytes` as a variable name because it shadows the built-in type. Also, it seems like you forgot to rewind the BytesIO pointer to the beginning. So do smth like `bytes.seek(0)` before that `audio_file =` line and maybe it'll work. P.S. You should distill your example to something that breaks, all of that HTTP stuff is totally unrelated.

Comment: @webKnjaZ Thank you for your comment, i've already improved the code and problem description. Unfortunately, adding `buffer.seek(0)` after writing to buffer didn't change anything.

Comment: Is it possible to pass the file handle directly to AudioFile?

`sr.AudioFile(ufile.file)`

Maybe you need to seek first.

`ufile.file.seek(0)`

Comment: @bddap That doesn't solve the problem, i get the same error.

Comment: Did you fix it or find another package?

Comment: @Walter I figured out that error occurs only when .flac audio file is uploaded, so I switched to .wav format.

Comment: @Artem, thanks. I'm converting every audio / video file that is not .WAV to .WAV, besides that I'm using `seek` / interface that receives a file like object or a path.